# XML for AlertDialog?

Tags: java, android

I am quite happy about how the standard AlertDialog looks. With a “yes-button”, and a “no-button”.

However I want my AlertDialog to also have a switch with a listener.  As I understand it I need to create my own custom AlertDialog to achieve this.

My question is can I find the XML file for the standard AlertDialog and its buttons?

**Edit:** I know  how to create a custom alert dialog. I am looking for the XML to the standard alert dialog. So that I can build my custom alert dialog with that as the template.

[image: picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the `xml` of the standard AlertDialog retrieved from the standard `jar` file of the `AndroidX AppCompat library`:

#### abc_alert_dialog_material.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
     Copyright (C) 2015 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AlertDialogLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parentPanel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="start|left|top"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/abc_alert_dialog_title_material"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentPanel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="48dp">

        <View android:id="@+id/scrollIndicatorUp"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="1dp"
              android:layout_gravity="top"
              android:background="?attr/colorControlHighlight"
              android:visibility="gone"/>

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipToPadding="false">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.widget.Space
                    android:id="@+id/textSpacerNoTitle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_dialog_padding_top_material"
                    android:visibility="gone"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@android:id/message"
                    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="?attr/dialogPreferredPadding"
                    android:paddingRight="?attr/dialogPreferredPadding"/>

                <android.widget.Space
                    android:id="@+id/textSpacerNoButtons"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_dialog_padding_top_material"
                    android:visibility="gone"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

        <View android:id="@+id/scrollIndicatorDown"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="1dp"
              android:layout_gravity="bottom"
              android:background="?attr/colorControlHighlight"
              android:visibility="gone"/>

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/customPanel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="48dp">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/custom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </FrameLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/abc_alert_dialog_button_bar_material"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</androidx.appcompat.widget.AlertDialogLayout>
```

Comment: Cool thanks man! :)